# How to call another worker when I have an ongoing call using twilio

Tags: php, codeigniter, twilio

I am trying to transfer an ongoing call to another worker but before I can transfer the caller. First I need to hold  the caller and call the desired worker if he/she is available. The problem is that when I call the desired worker, the caller automatically Hang's up.

```
public function transferToAgent(){
    $client = $this->init_client();
    $call = $client->account->calls->get($_POST["CallSid"]);
    $call->update(array(            
        "Url" => HTTP_BASE_URL."agent/call_controls/forward_agent?data=".$_POST['agentname'],
        "Method" => "POST"
    ));
}
public function forward_agent(){
    $agentname = $_GET['data'];
    $this->gabbyvilletwilio->AgentTransfer($agentname);
}
```

And this is my code where I call the other Agent

```
function AgentTransfer($agentname){
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml;
    $response->say(
        'Your call is now being transferred to your desired agent.',
        ['voice' => 'alice', 'language' => 'en-GB']
    );
    $dial = $response->dial();
    $dial->client($agentname);
    print $response;
}
```

Comment: Already closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The problem you have is that when you redirect one leg of the call, the other leg of the call becomes disconnected and has no other actions to perform from their TwiML, so hangs up as the call is complete for them.

There are a number of ways to get around this. As you are trying for what sounds like a warm transfer from one agent to another, then I recommend you take a read through this tutorial on [warm transfers in PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/warm-transfer/php/laravel). It is written for Laravel, but I'm sure you could translate to Codeigniter.

In brief though, the tutorial uses [`<Conference>`](http://twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) rather than connecting callers with [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number) so that the connection isn't broken. Then, instead of redirecting a call, you can put the caller on hold and invite another agent into the conference, unholding and transferring the caller when both agents are ready.

Let me know if that helps.